# Will copy-on-write in main memory work while swap is off?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, ram

> without overcommitment, every fork() would require enough free storage
>   to duplicate the address space, even though the vast majority of pages
>   never undergo copy-on-writes.

The above statement is taken from Robert Love's book (Linux System Programming 2nd edition, Memory management chapter, Overcommitting and OOM topic).

If we turned off the swap I can't overcommit the main memory. In this scenario will copy-on-write in main memory work (i.e for fork, malloc, mmap, etc) or it will try to pre-allocate the whole data in memory without any lazy allocation mechanism?

kindly correct me if i am missing anything.

Update:
      Friends, initially I thought I can't overcommit once we turned off the swap. As like below mentioned in the discussion we can overcommit even we turn off the swap.

Comment: @ilkkachu If you want to know what memory overcommitment is, try this: `for(int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) if(!malloc(1ul << 32)) err(1, "malloc");` No malloc fails on my old x86-64 laptop, despite allocating ten thousand times more memory than its ram + swap combined.

Comment: @UncleBilly tnx for pointing the mistake. Next time addition to down vote please add a comment too so that we will know what is wrong in the question and we will try to correct it. I have asked a question to Johan, If possible kindly leave your answer, It will be helpful.

Comment: @Karthik It's hard to tell what exactly will happen in your 500mb/10mb example, because both the userland malloc and the vm subsystem in kernel use some extra memory as metadata (to keep track of the allocations & their size), and the malloc may fail because of that. But if you write to virtual memory for which the kernel cannot find any backing (because it has overcommitted itself), the kernel will select a process and kill it (which may or may not be your process) to get its memory back. The infamous "OOM Killer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overcommit without swap. The word "storage" in Robert Love's book in this context refers to physical RAM. The kernel sets up a memory space for the process that does not yet contain mappings to physical RAM, or points to shared page frames, in the case of Copy-on-Write. The mappings are created on demand, when the pages are accessed. The assumption is that not all mappings are needed at the same time, so it is relatively safe to overcommit.

Comment: Tnx johan, If i have 500 mb of RAM (swap is off) and i am actively using all 500 mb. In this given scenorio if i tried to allocate a memory of 10 mb using malloc, will it return success? If yes what will happen if i tried to write on that memory?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article: [pivotal - Overcommit](http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/virtual_memory_settings_in_linux_-_the_problem_with_overcommit/)

There is actually a default memory limit, depending on configuration of 
`/proc/sys/vm/` files. If you set to "no overcommit", and choose a percentage, you get:

`Memory Allocation Limit = Swap Space + RAM * (Overcommit Ratio / 100)`

The default ratio is 50(%); With 4G RAM and 4G Swap this gives 6G as allocation limit.

In this special "no-overcommit" mode (via `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`) the *overcommitment* means how much of swap you count on using actively. This makes sense, because if you allocate 8 GB, and use them heavily, it will be too slow. So swap space "counts" half.

---

If you want a limit strictly the size of RAM, with no swap, you can set overcommit_memory to 2 (=no overcommit) and overcommit_ratio to 100%.

In the default case the kernel *does* some checking:

> a heuristic algorithm is applied to figure out if enough memory is
>   available.

(the third mode is: no check, i.e. overcommit until OOM happens)